# how to avoid mirror stream from getusermedia

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, getusermedia

i am using [react-multimedia-capture](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multimedia-capture) to record video. initially displaying video stream from getUserMedia, but i am getting mirror image in video stream. Looked for one of the snippet to flip by using css 
"-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);  transform: scaleX(-1);" but video is recording from the original stream only. Could someone help me out i need to record video without mirror image.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This isn't normal.

It probably has nothing to do with your code.  It's likely that your camera is configured to do this.  Check your webcam settings.

Comment: Thanks @Brad i will check with that.